# JWT With Role Based Access Control

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, rbac

Say I want to use JWT for authentication, and in the case of users who are using the API of my application directly I would like to issue a token that does not expire (but does contain an ID so that it can be revoked).  Secondly, say I have a role based access system, where I would also like to encode the user's role into the token.  However, how do I solve the problem that the user's role may change but that the token would still encode it? Obviously if someone's role changed to some thing with less privileges this would be a security issue?  The issue isn't just restricted to this use case either, theoretically active tokens would have the same problem of role changes not taking immediate affect.

My initial solution is too not encode role/permission levels into the primary token, and instead use a secondary token that would only be added to request to my system upon passing through the application's boundary from the greater internet, but I'm also wondering how other people solve this problem?

Comment: Since you want token's which are not supposed to expire. One approach you could take is having 2 level of access token's. One which are embedded into your JWT token and another which actually control the access to your resources. You would have to maintain a mapping of both types of tokens somewhere for a user, but this will allow you to control the permissions dynamically without changing anything into the JWT.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to invalidate tokens, you'll have to keep track of the tokens you issued and make sure you can "remove" them at some point in time.

My suggestion would be to use one token, and track somewhere a relation between `USER` and `TOKEN_VALID_IF_ISSUED_AFTER`.

At that point, when a user logs out, when their permissions change, when they change password... ...you can insert a record in this table with `$USER_ID` and `NOW()`.

Next time a token goes through your API you validate that it was issued after the `TOKEN_VALID_IF_ISSUED_AFTER` through the [iat](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519.html#section-4.1.6) claim -- if not, the user will have to get a brand new token.